# How to deploy JDBC jar file in my eclipse?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am new to eclipse and java full stack. I want to make a project in java full-stack.

For the front-end part - HTML, CSS, JavaScript 
For the back-end part - Java 
database - Derby 
server - Tomcat

I have successfully completed the front-end and server installation. I am stuck at JDBC.

How I tried to deploy JDBC:

1. created Dynamic web app
2. tried to bring jdbc.jar file in WEB-INF/lib (didn't work).
   other process - Build path/configure build path/classpath/add jar file
3. tried this code:

```
package testing; import java.sql.Connection;

public class check {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Connection dbConnection = null;

try {

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing";

Properties info = new Properties();

info.put("user", "root"); info.put("password", "test");

dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, info);

if (dbConnection != null) {

System.out.println("Successfully connected to MySQL database test");

}

} catch (SQLException ex) {

System.out.println("An error occurred while connecting MySQL databse");

ex.printStackTrace();package testing; import java.sql.Connection;

public class check {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Connection dbConnection = null;

try {

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing";

Properties info = new Properties();

info.put("user", "root"); info.put("password", "test");

dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, info);

if (dbConnection != null) {

System.out.println("Successfully connected to MySQL database test");

}

} catch (SQLException ex) {

System.out.println("An error occurred while connecting MySQL databse");

ex.printStackTrace();
```

Error I am get:

> An error occurred while connecting MySQL databse
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/te

Comment: You say `java database - DERBY`, but use `jdbc:mysql` , Why ?

Comment: Put `mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar` in tomcat  `lib` directory.

Comment: If you use Derby as you say, why are you trying to connect to MySQL. Use the correct JDBC URL for derby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have not added the MySQL JDBC Driver to your IDE's classpath. Since you're using Eclipse, here's an approach you could try:

Go to https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/ and download the latest version of the MySQL Connector by selecting your system specs.

1. Go to your project in your IDE and right-click it. Then go to Build Path -> Configure Build Path.
2. Click on Add External JARs and go to the location where you downloaded the MySQL Connector.
3. Select the MySQL Connector and open it. The JAR file will be added to your project's build path.
4. Click on apply and close. Run your application again and the problem should be gone.

Edit:

As Mark pointed out (thanks!), you said you're using Derby as your database.

So, the above steps won't work indeed.

Here's what you can do do try to solve your issue:

First of all, you're declaring

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing";
```

Since you're using derby, you should do something like this

```
private static String databaseUrl = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/yourDatabase;create=true;user=your_user;password=your_password";

private static void createConnection()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        // gets a connection
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl); 
    }
    catch (Exception except)
    {
        except.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Documentation reference: https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/start_toc.html

Hope this solves your issue!

Comment: If the OP is using Derby as they say, then adding MySQL Connector/J is the wrong thing to do.